# Specify CSS Polygon relative to right/top edges

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to specify a polygon in CSS using points relative to the edges of the element?

I'm using `clip-path` to create clipped corners on images. They need to be very specifically at an angle of 55%.

If I use percentages to specify an octagon, then the angle depends on the aspect-ratio of the image element. For example:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    29% 0, 71% 0, 100% 29%, 100% 71%, 71% 100%, 29% 100%, 0 71%, 0 29%
  );
```

What I'd like to do is specify points relative to the top, left, right and bottom edges of the element, probably in em. So theoretically, something like:

```
polygon(left+0.7em top, right-0.7em 0, ...)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, at least in Chrome you can. You can just use css calc when specifying a polygon.

For example

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(
  64px 0, calc(100% - 64px) 0, 100% 92px, 100% calc(100% - 92px),
  calc(100% - 64px) 100%, 64px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 92px), 0 92px );
```

Will give you a nice octagon with angles of ±55deg.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue as the vertical and horizontal coordinates as being relative to the images height and width - if only you could specify the vertical position as a percentage of the width (if the image is portrait) for example.

Using relative units would solve it I think if you know the dimension of the image in those units. Whatever the solution it looks like you need to clip the image so that it's square shaped so you're only showing a portion of images that aren't 1:1.

The only solution I can think of is to make the image a background of a div where you supply the dimension which is the shape of a square and then make the background image cover that div so that if it's portrait the height is clipped, if it's landscape then the width is clipped (it'll fill the background clipping the least possible). Then apply the clip-path to that div.

HTML

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
    height: 24em;
    width: 24em; 
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: url(yourimg.png) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(29% 0, 71% 0, 100% 29%, 100% 71%, 71% 100%, 29% 100%, 0 71%, 0 29%);
    clip-path: polygon(29% 0, 71% 0, 100% 29%, 100% 71%, 71% 100%, 29% 100%, 0 71%, 0 29%);
}
```

You can adjust the dimensions to whatever you want of course. I think with relative units this still fits the need for responsiveness and might even be a bit more flexible than inline images but possibly less ideal in terms of usability (you could possibly look at shifting the inline image out of view and using ::after to create and style the background version).